# Boxing/unboxing, changing the copy of the refence of the boxed value does not refected to the boxed value

Tags: c#, types, reference, boxing, unboxing

So I read through [the documentation of Microsoft here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing).

Consider the following code:

```cs
int i = 0;
object o = i;
object p = o;

o = 1;
p = 2;

Console.WriteLine($"o:{o}, p:{p}");
//output o:1, p:2
```

My understanding is that boxing happen on `object o = i;`, now **o** is a refence to the value in heap. Then **p** is assigned to be same as **o**.

Why isn't the change of **p** refected to **o**? Aren't they pointing to the same address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your understanding is incorrect; the line

```
 object p = o;
```

assigns `p` the same reference; however:

```
o = 1;
```

creates a *new* object (boxed integer) and assigns the *new* reference to `o`; `o` and `p` are now different references;

```
p = 2;
```

then does the same with *yet another* boxed object and reference

---

Your expectation *is* how "ref locals" work, however:

```cs
int i = 0;
ref int o = ref i;
ref int p = ref o;

o = 1;
Console.WriteLine(i); // 1
p = 2;
Console.WriteLine(i); // 2
```